# Looking for a more performant way to retrieve the top two rows of a group in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-performance

I'm looking for a performant way to retrieve the top TWO rows for each group of data in SQL. I have a very large table of data (about 10 billion rows). Each row of data is described by four dimensions (which make up the primary key) and the table is partitioned by one of the dimensions (the last column of the primary key).

```
-- Medium table (2 to 3 million rows)
CREATE TABLE [smallDatabase].[dbo].[dimTableA] (
    [colA] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,[valueA] [int]
);

-- Small table (<1000 rows)
CREATE TABLE [smallDatabase].[dbo].[dimTableB] (
    [colB] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,[valueB] [int]
);

-- Small table (<10000 rows)
CREATE TABLE [smallDatabase].[dbo].[dimTableC] (
    [colC] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,[valueC] [int]
);

-- Small table (100 to 200 rows)
CREATE TABLE [smallDatabase].[dbo].[dimTableD] (
    [colD] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,[grouperD] [int] NOT NULL
    ,[dateD] [date]
);

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [pfColD](int) AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (1, 2, 3, ..., n);
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [psColD] AS PARTITION [pfColD] TO ([PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], ..., [PRIMARY]);

-- Large table (~10 billion rows)
CREATE TABLE [bigDatabase].[dbo].[factBigTable] (
    [colA] [int] NOT NULL
    ,[colB] [int] NOT NULL
    ,[colC] [int] NOT NULL
    ,[colD] [int] NOT NULL
    ,[datum] [float] NULL
    ,PRIMARY KEY (
        [colA] ASC
        ,[colB] ASC
        ,[colC] ASC
        ,[colD] ASC
    )
) ON psColD([colD]);
```

One other requirement is that I only need to do this for a subset of data at any time. To represent the data which needs to be located, lets use a temp table to filter.

```
CREATE TABLE #filter (
    [colA] [int] NOT NULL
    ,[colB] [int] NOT NULL
    ,PRIMARY KEY (
        [colA] ASC
        ,[colB] ASC
    )
);
```

I've found some other solutions online which suggest using row number selecting the top 2, like so:

```
-- Get the most recent two data points for each group of data
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT big.*
        ,dimD.[grouperD]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY dimD.[grouperD], big.[colA], big.[colB], big.[colC]
            ORDER BY dimD.[dateD] DESC
        ) AS rowNumber
    FROM [bigDatabase].[dbo].[factBigTable] AS big
    INNER JOIN [smallDatabase].[dbo].[dimTableD] AS dimD
        ON big.[colD] = dimD.[colD]
    INNER JOIN #filter
        ON big.[colA] = #filter.[colA]
            AND big.[colB] = #filter.[colB]
) AS bigDataRanked
WHERE rowNumber <= 2;
```

This does indeed get me the exact data that I'm looking for; however, it's mighty slow!

I've tried a bunch of different solutions at this point but all have performed slower than I'd like. It's worth noting that due to the nature of the data, not every dimension combination has data. Some combinations are quite sparse.

One algorithm I tried looked great on paper, but ended up performing very slowly due to the sparse nature of the data. The idea was:

1. Cache a list of each group. I.e., [grouperD], [colA], [colB], and [colC]. Keep track for rows found for each group.
2. Cursor over [colD], ordered by [dateD]. Stop when each group has 2 rows found.
3. Select rows from [factBigTable] which match groups where rows found is less than 2. Cache the results.
4. For cached results increment the rows found count.
5. Move cached results to a staging table for later consumption.
6. Continue to next [colD] in loop.

Each loop performed relatively quickly, since SQL is able to use PK seeks on most of the queries. However, some of my groups had very low max [colD], so the loop had to iterate many times.

The fastest solution I've found so far looks terrible on paper, but ends up performing the best. However; it's still slower than I'd like AND it scales very poorly.

1. For the subset of data we care about (i.e., join to the filter), cache all the primary keys for each group.
2. Select and cache the max [colD] for each group.
3. Delete the max value from the PK by group list.
4. Select and cache the max [colD] for each group, again. To get the second to max [colD].
5. Use the max and second to max cached keys to look up all the rows we need.

**Does anyone have any other ideas on how to quickly retrieve the rows that I'm looking for?** By no means does this need to be done in a single query. I'm okay with as many staging or temp tables as needed to get the data quickly. Additionally, I'm *open* to adding indexes or other data model changes. I'd prefer not to - just because the table is so big, any change will likely mean significant storage considerations -but, if it's the only way, then I'll make it work.

Comment: Did you run an explain on the query that works?  Probably just need an index.

Comment: Using a cursor is definitely not going to be a good option. Looping is horribly inefficient as it essentially has to run 10 billion queries to look at every single row. I'm with @Hogan, indexing is almost certainly the best option here.

Comment: You'll likely get some great ideas by searching for "top n in group" Itzik Ben Gan shows a variety of solutions [here](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/optimizing-top-n-group-queries) and there are other [similar questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86415/retrieving-n-rows-per-group) with detailed answers to other questions on dba.stackexchange.com. I'd be more inclined to ask on dba.stackexchange.com how a table of that size and structure should be partitioned to allow for effective and efficient queries to be written against it.

Answer (score 0):

can't comment, not big enough, but curious, what edition of sql server are we talking about?

I doubt it'll be faster (especially if we talkin' billions of rows prior to rowNumber <= 2), but I would always prefer to offload the row_number() operation to a smaller subset if able.

```
;with bigDataRanked as (
SELECT big.*
        ,dimD.[grouperD]
        ,dimD.[dateD]
    FROM [bigDatabase].[dbo].[factBigTable] AS big
    INNER JOIN [smallDatabase].[dbo].[dimTableD] AS dimD
        ON big.[colD] = dimD.[colD]
    INNER JOIN #filter
        ON big.[colA] = #filter.[colA]
            AND big.[colB] = #filter.[colB]
) 
select bdr.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY bdr.[grouperD], bdr.[colA], bdr.[colB], bdr.[colC]
            ORDER BY bdr.[dateD] DESC) rowNumber
from bigDataRanked bdr -- will have an additional column dateD returned from dimTableD (from bdr.*)
where rowNumber <= 2;
```